# Test Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS code in visual studio

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, continuous-integration

Hy.

I want to create a `Xamarin` application with `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android` support.

My project structure is basically:
Xamarin.Android
Xamarin.iOS
Core (PCL)
Core.Test (with xunit)

My problem is that i want to test my platform specific code that is in the `Xamarin.Android` and `.iOS` projects.
The only solution i found is that I create an Android unit test app, switch the nunit lite to xunit and with the xunit.runner.devices package i can run the test on a simulator or a phisycal device.
I've tried to create an `Android PCL` and reference the Android project but the `visual studio` test explorer and the vstest.console.exe (with the testadapter configured) can't run the tests in the `dll`.

My problem is that i want to test the code in the platform specific projects in continous integration.

Is there any solution to create an `Android.Test/iOS.Test` project that can reference to the Android/iOS project and run unit tests in a console runner?

Comment: Console runner won't be able to test platform specific code.

Comment: I've got the same problem.

@Cheesebaron is there any way to run these in CI?

Comment: You could start some simulators or attach real devices to the CI server.

Comment: Cheesebaron is right.  You can't run platform specific code in a console runner.  But if your code is not platform specific then you can write it in your PCL and if it is platform specific then you need the platform so there is no point running it in a console runner.  My original question (and I think yours too)  was about the mixed case when you write some platform specific behavior which is not using any platform service.  In this case I think your best shot is really using some emulator.  With that you will be able to run UI tests too so it's a win ☺️